# Firebase Cloud Functions sometimes not executing until the end of the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

If I have a cloud function like this, will the function setData() always execute until the end of the function(console either "successfully set data!" or "could not set data")? Because I have a function set up in a similar manner as this and it sometimes seems to stop executing in the middle of its execution.

```
function setData() {
  admin.database().ref(`someLocation`).set(true)
  .then(() => {
    return admin.database().ref(`anotherLocation`).set(true)
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("successfully set data!")
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("could not set data", err)
  })
}


exports.newPotentialMember = functions.database.ref('listenLocation')
  .onCreate(event => {

    setData()

})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not returning any value from your `newPotentialMember` right now. That means that Cloud Functions can stop execution of your code as soon as `newPotentialMember` returns, which is straight after `setData` **starts**. Since writing to the database happens asynchronously, you have to return a promise from `newPotentialMember` that resolves after all writes have completed.

```
function setData() {
  return admin.database().ref(`someLocation`).set(true)
  .then(() => {
    return admin.database().ref(`anotherLocation`).set(true)
  })
}


exports.newPotentialMember = functions.database.ref('listenLocation')
  .onCreate(event => {
    return setData()
})
```

I recommend you carefully read the [Firebase documentation on synchronous functions, asynchronous functions, and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).